# Unable to execute AutoIt script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoit, scite

I installed [AutoIt extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Damien.autoit) and when I run the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> it executes but does not display the form to enter IP details. Same script in SciTE editor is working fine.

[image]

How can I make my AutoIt script run in Visual Studio code?

Comment: `Reason I moved to visual studio code is due to debugging features which Scite editor lacks and it is very difficult to troubleshoot the flow of the script.` Can you point me to description of how you can debug AutoIt script in a "better way" ?

Comment: AutoIt is an interpreted language you should make breakpoints and watch in your code bo creating `MsgBox()` or `ConsoleWrite()` or any other invention. There are some projects like [raphical AutoIt Debugger](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/21834-graphical-autoit-debugger/).

Answer (score 1):

AutoIt extension for Visual Studio Code requires [SciTE4Autoit3](https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?../autoit3/scite/download/SciTE4AutoIt3.exe), not just the version that comes with the AutoIt installer.